# Query lookup in spring data with '_' or '%' as part of the string being searched?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to configure Spring Data to ignore characters like '_' and '%' when they are entered in the query search strings?

Right now, using the Containing keyword to make the query method. If the search keyword contains - '_' or '%', they are not treated as the characters '_' or '%'.

What is the approach if i want such characters to be treated as the characters 'as they are' - not influencing query results? I am using Spring Data JPA (1.7) with Hibernate.

Or should the escaping be done 'externally'?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these are your options

- If you define the method as `findBySomething`, the query will be translated to `something = <param>`. In this case, `_` or `%` won't matter
- If you define the method as `findBySomethingLike`, the query will be translated to `something like %<param>%`. Obviously, `_` and `%` will be applied
- If you define the method as `findBySomethingStartingWith`, the query will be translated to `something like %<param>`
- If you define the method as `findBySomethingEndingWith`, the query will be translated to `something like <param>%`
- If you define the method as `findBySomethingContaining`, the query will be translated to `something like %<param>%`

[Related JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-111)

JPQL supports `ESCAPE` keyword which can be used to specify the escape character used in the query ([link](https://blogs.oracle.com/JPQL01/entry/how_to_use_like_expression))

```
String ejbql = "SELECT i from Item i WHERE i.name LIKE :pattern ESCAPE
:esc";
Query query = em.createQuery(ejbql);
query.setParameter("pattern", "\\\\_%");
query.setParameter("esc", '\\\\');
List result = query.getResultList();
```

> As you can see, two backslashes are used in setParameter(). The first backslash is processed by Java compiler and the second backslash is processed by JPQL compiler. And the result is to match string having '_'.

But, afaik there isn't a way to use this declaratively with spring data so you'd have to use a custom repository implementation.

Comment: Four backslashes in single quotes won't compile, fyi.. and having the four backslashes as a string won't work. needs to be two.